# How to check a sheet is exist in current workbook or not

Tags: excel, validation, vba

I have banch of sheet in one workbook and I want to find out anyone of the sheet from that sheet present in Workbook and also I want to check the different sheet (as per cell value data) exist in workbook or not.If sheet is present in Workbook then open(Active)that sheet.If sheet not present in workbook then show msg "sheet is not present."and return back to textbox.

Comment: Please add what you have tried already. This isn't a code writing site

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a simple function like this:

```
Function sheetIsValid(sheetName As String) As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    sheetIsValid = False
    For Each ws In Sheets()
        If (UCASE(ws.Name) = UCASE(sheetName)) Then
            sheetIsValid = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

and use it like this:

```
Sub TEST()
    If (Not sheetIsValid("Sheet2")) Then
        MsgBox "sheet is not present."
    Else
        '/* some stuff */
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thanx 
   but when sheet is present in workbook then automatically open(Active).and when sheet is not Exist in this workbook then show msg "sheet is not Exist."